# Show that it is not possible for $A$ and $B$ to meet at a point

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

> Two friends $A$ and $B$ are initially at points $(0,0)$ and $(12,7)$ respectively on the infinite grid plane. $A$ and $B$ takes steps of sizes $4$ and $6$ units respectively along the grid lines. Show that it is not possible for them to meet at a point. An exaple step- $A$ takes three steps towards right and one upwards($3+1=4$).
>   [image]

I moved $A$ three times towards right on the x axis($12$ steps), so that it is now vertically below $B$ Now I moved $B$ one time($6$ steps) vertically downward towards $A$ Now $B$ is just one unit above $A$. What next? Am I on the right track?

Comment: What can you say about the $x$ and $y$ coordinates $modulo\ 2$?

Comment: $$X_A \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$  $$Y_A \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$  $$X_B \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$ $$Y_B \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

Comment: Please tell me how to apply these results.

Comment: @amityas Can $Y_B=Y_A$?

Comment: Can anyone please figure out a proper solution.

Comment: @kingW3 No, never

Comment: Right; so there you go

Comment: @kingW3 Aaah!!! Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: @kingW3 No!!!!!! It can not be a proper solution. $A$ can move 1 unit towards right and three upwards. Then again 4 upwards to get a Y coordinate 7

Comment: @amityas No matter,if you change $Y_B$ to be even then $X_B$ has to be  odd. Also perhaps you could mention that one doesn't have to move $4$ steps in one direction exclusively, but can move $3$ right and $1$ down for example.

Comment: @kingW3 I did not get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $X_A$ and $Y_A$ have to be of the same parity because you start at $(0,0)$ and if you move $x$ steps to right or left and $y$ steps to top or bottom by the rule you have $x+y=4$ and the sum of an odd and an even is always odd so it must be the case that $x,y$ are both even or they are both odd. So $X_A+x$ and $Y_A+y$ are of the same parity.

Now similarly $X_B$ and $Y_B$ must have different parities since you start at $(0,1)$ now you have $x+y=6$ which again implies that $x,y$ have the same parities which implies that $X_B+x$ and $Y_B+y$ have different parities.

Comment: I started from $(12,7)$ in case of $B$ and not $(0,1)$.

Comment: @amityas Yeah, my mistake, was in a hurry. Anyway $(12,7)$ is equivalent with $(0,1)$ if you apply your transformation also since you're looking at the parity $12\equiv 0,7\equiv 1\pmod{2}$.

Comment: so should i edit?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your method won't really help you prove it fully.  You seem to be trying to prove that one particular route won't work;  but the question is asking for you to prove that it's impossible, i.e., out of *all* the possible things A and B could do, none of them will allow A and B to meet up.

Here's a hint on how to prove that it's impossible:  Make a list of a bunch of points that A can get to by taking steps of 4 or 6 units.   Now make a list of a bunch of points that B can get to.  See if there are any points in common between the two lists (if you've done it right, there won't be.)  More importantly, look for patterns & commonalities within each list, and see if you can discern why it's impossible for them to meet up.  If you spot a pattern, try to figure out why it arises.

Comment: What do you mean by making a list?

Comment: There will be infinite of them

Comment: @amityas:  Yup, there are an infinite number of possibilities for each person.  But you might (should) be able to see a pattern once you write down several possibilities for both A and B.  You'll then need to make an argument that *all* of the points reachable by A and B follow this pattern;  but I don't think it'll be that hard to do.

Comment: I am unable to understand your point. How can I by showing some result for some points can conclude its same for all points?

Comment: @amityas: The point of making the lists is to figure out what the pattern might be in the first place.  Once you have a hypothesis for what the pattern is, *then* you would need to prove it in general.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but look at the x-coordinates of the points in your list that A can reach. Same for the y-coordinates. Repeat the exercise for B. If you just consider a few points that each can reach, you should be able to see a patttern. Can you prove that the pattern will always hold?

Comment: @Nick Wait, let me take the pen

Comment: I can not figure out anything!